# jQuery Append in the Loop printing undefinied

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

jQuery loop for jSON response:

```
success: function (response) {

// response contains 100 job posts in jSON format

    $.each(response, function(k) {

    // the below inline HTML switched to line breaks for easy reading.

    var data = 
      "<div class='job-details'>
         <div id='job-title'>"+response[k]['title']+"</div>   
         <div id='job-company'>"+response[k]['company']+"</div>
         <div class='text' id='job-category'>"+response[k]['company']+"</div>
         <div class='text' id='job-type'>"+response[k]['type']+"</div>
         <div class='text' id='job-salary'>"+response[k]['salary']+"</div>
         <div class='job-description' id='job-description'>"+response[k] ['shortdesc']+"</div>
      </div>";
    });
$("#jobs-list").append(data);
```

Its suppose to display

// Loop 1

```
job title 1
job company 1
job category 1
job type 1
job salary 1
job description 1
```

// Loop 2

```
job title 2
job company 2
job category 2
job type 2
job salary 2
job description 2
```

Its rather displaying as

// Loop 1

```
job title 1
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

// Loop 2

```
undefined
job category 1
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

How to get all the data of each loop to show based on index of the array? I know when I use response[indexnumber] instead of response[k] would work but how to get the count of array and loop it based on the index number?

Comment: please ``console.log(response)`` inside in your success function and say what is the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
  var data = `<div class='job-details'>
  <div id='job-title'>` + arr[index] + `</div>
  <div id='job-company'>` + arr[index] + `</div>
  <div id='job-category'>` + arr[index] + `</div>
  <div id='job-type'>` + arr[index] + `</div>
  <div id='job-salary'>` + arr[index] + `</div>
  <div id='job-description'>` + arr[index] + `</div>
  </div>`;
  $("#jobs-list").append(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='jobs-list'></div>
```

Note:- You are displaying the data the correct way but something went wrong with loop and quotes so you can check that. Here is one little example.

Answer (score 0):

I supposed your response is correct. your mistake is in here `<div id='job-title'>"+response[k]['title']+"</div>` it should be like this one `<div id='job-title'>"+k.title+"</div>` so your code sould be like below:

```
success: function (response) {
// response contains 100 job posts in jSON format
    $.each(response, function(i,k) {
    // the below inline HTML switched to line breaks for easy reading.
    var data = 
        "<div class='job-details'>
             <div id='job-title'>"+k.title+"</div>   
             <div id='job-company'>"+k.company+"</div>
             <div class='text' id='job-category'>"+k.company+"</div>
             <div class='text' id='job-type'>"+k.type+"</div>
             <div class='text' id='job-salary'>"+k.salary+"</div>
             <div class='job-description' id='job-description'>"+k.shortdesc+"</div>
        </div>";
});
$("#jobs-list").append(data);
```

I hope this solves your problem, but if not please share what is your `console.log(response`).